# Changing size of SVG logo animated or with transition

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, css-animations

I am using the following code to change the size of the logo when the user slides down the page. Am trying to add a transition delay in the SVG size change with no luck. Can you please help me?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="tm-navbar">
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
<div class="tm-navbar-center">
<div class="tm-nav-logo uk-hidden-small">
<a class="tm-logo uk-hidden-small" href="#">
<img class="uk-responsive-height uk-responsive-width" src="/images/logo.svg">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.tm-navbar-fixed.tm-navbar-animated .tm-navbar img { height: 110px; }
.tm-navbar-fixed.tm-navbar-animated .tm-navbar-small img { height: 70px; }
```

**JS**

```
// Fullscreen image & transparent fixed menu
var fn              = function(){},
    win            = $(window),
    body            = $('body'),
    navbar          = $('.tm-navbar');

if(body.hasClass('tm-navbar-fixed')) {
    win.on('scroll', function() {
        if (win.scrollTop() > 0) { navbar.addClass('tm-navbar-small'); } 
        else { navbar.removeClass('tm-navbar-small'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried tinkering with `.tm-navbar img { -webkit-transition: height .2s; }` ?

Comment: @above, you'll need to have a height set initially to transition from. Should work with a SVG, too http://jsfiddle.net/o9k1ja2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.tm-navbar-fixed.tm-navbar-animated .tm-navbar img { height: 110px; transition: height .2s; }
.tm-navbar-fixed.tm-navbar-animated .tm-navbar-small img { height: 70px; }
```

I updated CSS code with transition @Evan mentioned and worked. Thanks a lot!